# List values are correct when printed but List is empty when using using it Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, setstate

I have a screen that receives states through a `BlocListener` and  `ListView.builder` builds UI based on  `List<UserRoute> routes`.  So I use `setState()` to assign new values to `routes` and UI should update but it doesn't. I print values for both state and routes in BlocListener and they are all correct. I then did a test using just a `ListView` with a single child `Text(routes.isNotEmpty ? '${routes.first.routeName}' : 'routes is Empty')`  and even after receiving the state the child prints 'routes is Empty', meaning that `routes` didn't get updated. Can you see what's happening?

This is the screen:

```
    class SelectRouteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isIOS = Platform.isIOS ? true : false;

  User user;
  String routeName;
  SelectRouteScreen({@required this.user});
  @override
  _SelectRouteScreenState createState() => _SelectRouteScreenState();
}

class _SelectRouteScreenState extends State<SelectRouteScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AudioCache cache = new AudioCache();
    List<UserRoute> routes = [];
    cache.loadAll(['click.mp3', 'tableViewOpen.mp3', 'tableViewClose.mp3']);
    return BlocListener<RouteBloc, RouteState>(
      listener: (BuildContext context, RouteState state) {
        if (state is RoutesLoaded) {
          print(' SelectRouteScreen BlocListener state received');
          setState(() {
            routes = [];
            routes = state.userRoutes;
          });

          print(
              'SelectRouteScreen BlocListener incoming state routes are ${state.userRoutes.length}');
          print('SelectRouteScreen BlocListener routes are: $routes');
          print(
              'SelectRouteScreen BlocListener first route name is: ${routes.first.routeName}');
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: widget.isIOS
                  ? Icon(CupertinoIcons.back)
                  : Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                cache.play('tableViewClose.mp3');
                Navigator.pop(context, widget.routeName);
              }),
          title: Text(
//            '${routes.first.routeName}',
            'Seleziona tragitto',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.orange,
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                letterSpacing: 1),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(routes.isNotEmpty
                  ? '${routes.first.routeName}'
                  : 'routes is Empty ${routes.length}') // prints 'route is empty 0'
            ],
          ),
//          child: ListView.builder(
//            itemCount: routes.length,
//            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => RouteCell(
//              routeName: '${routes[index].routeName}',
//              isSelected: false,
//              onTap: () {
//                widget.routeName = routes[index].routeName;
//              },
//              onTapCancel: () {
//                widget.routeName = null;
//              },
//            ),
//          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this are the prints:

```
I/flutter (  350):  SelectRouteScreen BlocListener state received
I/flutter (  350): SelectRouteScreen BlocListener incoming state routes are 1
I/flutter (  350): SelectRouteScreen BlocListener routes are: [Route: {RO-112c206e-b1c2-4b03-969b-b07f544cf160,json try,0.22044000000000002,57.0,[LatLng(latitude:44.500714, longitude:11.335623), LatLng(latitude:44.500714, longitude:11.335623), LatLng(latitude:44.500714, longitude:11.335623), LatLng(latitude:44.500714, longitude:11.335623), LatLng(latitude:44.50054, longitude:11.335546), LatLng(latitude:44.50054, longitude:11.335546), LatLng(latitude:44.500518, longitude:11.335627), LatLng(latitude:44.500518, longitude:11.335627), LatLng(latitude:44.500518, longitude:11.335627), LatLng(latitude:44.500518, longitude:11.335627), LatLng(latitude:44.500492, longitude:11.335626), LatLng(latitude:44.500492, longitude:11.335626), LatLng(latitude:44.500471, longitude:11.335714), LatLng(latitude:44.500471, longitude:11.335714), LatLng(latitude:44.500471, longitude:11.335714), LatLng(latitude:44.500469, longitude:11.335778), LatLng(latitude:44.500469, longitude:11.335778), LatLng(latitude:44.500472, longitude:11.335865), LatLng(latitude:
I/flutter (  350): SelectRouteScreen BlocListener first route name is: json try
```

How can it be that prints are showing values but when using them I find none?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what was causing this. I had the `List<UserRoute> routes = [];`inside the build method. I moved it outside and it all works.